# How can I store jQuery id in a PHP variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to save this `"idDisplay"` value as a PHP variable? How can I store this?

This is my code:

```
<h1>id of selected tab: <span id="idDisplay"></span></h1>

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Proin dolor</a></li>
<li><a href="#3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1"><p>Proin </p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Morbi </p></div>
<div id="3"><p>Mauris </p></div>
</div>

<script>
function getSelectedTabId(){
return $("#tabs .ui-tabs-panel:visible").attr("id");
}
$(function() {
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
$("#tabs").click(function(e){
     $("#idDisplay").text(getSelectedTabId());
});
$("#tabs").click();
 });
 </script>
```

Currently I am getting selected tab id in `"idDisplay"` but I want to store this id as a PHP variable. I am a beginner in jQuery. Please help me to solve this. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use AJAX to send value to PHP file

Comment: how.?can  u help me.?i am beginner in jquery,and ajax.

Comment: u have to use AJAX because Jquery is Clientside and PHP is Serverside so u cant get anything to PHP when the Server already executed and the Client rendert the page.

Comment: Plenty of tutorials out there on how to use AJAX together with php, you just gotta start learning

Comment: @user5533614: Client-side code and server-side code can't interact.  They run in completely different contexts on completely different computers.  Don't think of it as "storing in a PHP variable".  What AJAX does is make HTTP requests in code.  Just like the request a browser makes when it loads a page, but simply in the background in JavaScript code.  What you would do is make such a request, including the value you want to store.  That request would be for a PHP "page" you build, which expects that value (GET or POST) and then performs whatever PHP logic you want to perform.

Comment: First time is enough or you need id every time the click?

Comment: first time is enough

Comment: If you are just trying to send this to another php page, just call the page like this: `http://mysiteurl/myphppage.php?idDisplay=155` and then in myphppage.php you can read that with `$_GET['idDisplay']`

Comment: AJAX is the only hope for you

Comment: Could you please explain what are you trying to achieve?Why you want to save it in php variable. . . so we can give you better suggestions.

Comment: i want to store this id in mysql so that later i can check which option selected before.

Answer (score 0):

In your click event:

```
$("#tabs").click(function(e){
    var selectedId = getSelectedTabId();
    $("#idDisplay").text(selectedId);

    $.post('get_selected_id.php', {selected_id: selectedId}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

PHP:
Create a file with the name you specified in the $.post() function as the first parameter. You can read more about jquery ajax on [this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) page.

```
<?php
//get_selected_id.php
$selected_id =  $_POST['selected_id']; //your id is stored here
?>
```

Comment: thank u and which files i want to change to get_selected_id.php file ??

Comment: You can just create a separate php file called get_selected_id.php and then the javascript will call that file using the ajax request.

Comment: sry for asking..what changes i want to do  my code.?which codes want to change in "get_selected_id.php" file.?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: i didn't get any result..iam changed my script with u given like this 

  `<h1>id of selected tab: <span id="idDisplay"></span></h1>
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><a href="#2">Proin dolor</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="1"><p>Proin </p></div>
<div id="2"><p>Morbi </p></div>
</div>
<script>
$("#tabs").click(function(e){
    var selectedId = getSelectedTabId();
    $("#idDisplay").text(selectedId);

    $.post('get_selected_id.php', {selected_id: selectedId}, function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
});</script>`